# Java: Distinguishing inputs in InputStream

Tags: java, networking

I have an `InputStream` which runs on a thread and reads any data which is passed over the network. My question is- how do I distinguish between the bytes received by the `InputStream` object? e.g. if the bytes received point to a Car object, do something, if bytes received point to a Person object, do something else.

Thanks.

EDIT: here's a snippet of my code. does it seem fine? sorry, im new to network programming.

```
private class ConnectedThread extends Thread {
        private final BluetoothSocket mmSocket;
        private final InputStream mmInStream;
        private final ObjectOutputStream mmObjOutStream;

        public ConnectedThread(BluetoothSocket socket) {
            Log.d(TAG, "create ConnectedThread");
            mmSocket = socket;
            InputStream tmpIn = null;
            ObjectOutputStream tmpOut = null;

            // Get the BluetoothSocket input and output streams
            try {
                tmpIn = socket.getInputStream();
                tmpOut = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "temp sockets not created", e);
            }

            mmInStream = tmpIn;
            mmObjOutStream = tmpOut;
        }

        public void run() {
            Log.i(TAG, "BEGIN mConnectedThread");
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int bytes;

            // Keep listening to the InputStream while connected
            while (true) {
                try {
                    // Read from the InputStream
                    bytes = mmInStream.read(buffer);
                    Log.i(TAG, "PERFORMING MESSAGE READ");
                    // Send the obtained bytes to the UI Activity
                    mHandler.obtainMessage(GameboardResourceActivity.MESSAGE_READ, bytes, -1, buffer)
                            .sendToTarget();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "disconnected", e);
                    connectionLost();
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        /**
         * Write to the connected OutStream.
         * @param buffer  The bytes to write
         */
        public void write(CardResource buffer) {
            try {
                mmObjOutStream.writeObject(buffer);
                System.out.println("Reached here at least........");
                // Share the sent message back to the UI Activity
                mHandler.obtainMessage(GameboardResourceActivity.MESSAGE_WRITE, -1, -1, buffer)
                        .sendToTarget();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Exception during write", e);
            }
        }

        public void cancel() {
            try {
                mmSocket.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "close() of connect socket failed", e);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Is it one continuous stream of bytes or is there once stream per object.

Comment: Are you expecting serialized Java objects on the input stream?

Comment: @Ted yes. these are serialised java objects which are instances of different classes.

Comment: @icirellik it is one continuous stream

Answer (score 1):

Well you do have to know what your application protocol is to understand it. It sounds like the other end is using Serialization, which you need to read up. See the Javadoc for ObjectOutputStream and ObjectInputStream. What you need is ObjectInputStream.readObject(), if this supposition is correct. If it isn't, you will just have to find out what they are sending you and proceed accordingly, probably with a DataInputStream to handle the various datatypes.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass yor sockets input stream directly into the constructor for ObjectInputStream:

```
ObjectInputStream inputStream = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
    
while ((obj = inputStream.readObject()) != null) {
    if (obj instanceof Person) {   
        System.out.println(((Person)obj).toString());
    }
}
```

---

#### EDIT

As the comments state this will prematurely exit if you pass a null value into your ObjectOutputStream on the other end. Its best to guard against this, null values are never a good thing to receive unexpectedly.

Comment: 1. `readObject()` returns null if you wrote a null, not otherwise. There is no reason to exit the loop if you read a null. The termination condition is an `EOFException`. 2.  
There is only one accessible constructor of ObjectOutputStream, and it takes an InputStream. No overload.